# Pass array to Laravel view and use that array as VueJS prop

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have an array variable `$screenshots` that I am trying to pass to my Laravel view. Usually, I would use the `@foreach` and loop through the array, but I want to pass the full array to a Vue component by defining it as a prop. I want to do this so that I can loop over the array in the component. I am getting the `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` error.

What is the proper way to do this with VueJS and Laravel?

Here is my blade template:

```
@section('content')

    <ticket-edit id="edit-ticket" single-ticket="{{ $ticket }}" screenshots="{{ $files }}">

    </ticket-edit>

@endsection
```

Here is my custom component (different file):

```
<script>
    export default {

        template: '#edit-ticket-template',

        props: ['SingleTicket', 'screenshots'],

        data: function() {
            return {
                ticket: [],
                screenshots: []
            };
        },

        methods: {
            getTicket() {
                return this.ticket = JSON.parse(this.SingleTicket);
            },

            getScreenshots() {
                return this.screenshots = JSON.parse(this.files);
            },

            createNotes: function () {
                var ticketNotes = $('.summernote');
                ticketNotes.summernote({
                    height: 260,
                    toolbar: [
                        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear', 'strikethrough']],
                        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                        ['para', ['ul', 'ol']],
                    ]
                });
            }
        },

        created: function() {
            this.getTicket();
            this.getScreenshots();
        },

        ready: function() {
            this.createNotes();
        }

    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:** When I am adding attachments, I am using `json_encode` to encode the path to the attachments. Then when I retrieve them, I run `json_decode` in my model like so `$files = json_decode($ticket->screenshots);` So my controller looks like this:

```
public function edit($sub_domain, $id)
{
    $ticket = Ticket::find($id);
    $files = json_decode($ticket->screenshots);

    return view('templates.tickets-single', compact('ticket', 'files'));
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am stuck at the same point

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This works - it was hard to find this answer on the web so I hope it helps! You have to bind it.

```
 <edit-ticket-template
      v-bind:SingleTicket="{{  json_encode($ticket) }}"
      v-bind: screenshots ="{{  json_encode($files) }}"
  >
  </edit-ticket-template>
```

Yeah I don't think you need to json_encode the single ticket but you get the point.

Answer (score 7):

I think Blade calls `htmlentities()` automatically when you write `{{ $ticket }}`.  Since `$ticket` is not a string, it is erroring.  Try `{{ json_encode($ticket) }}`

Comment: I updated my questions to show that I have already decoded the `attachments`. When I try it without decoding the attachments, I get an error in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `{!! json_encode($ticket) !!}}`

Comment: It can be more beautiful in HTML code and smaller file (actually not much if you enable Gzip) yet.
Be careful! This can cause a problem when your content contains ' or ", especially the content is generated by users.
Use {!! !!} only when you know exactly that you DO NOT meet the condition above. Otherwise escape string with {{ }} for safety sake.

Comment: @spicydog agree

Answer (score 1):

I use Laravel 7 and I faced the same problem.
and I use this solution and do

```
 {!! json_encode($ticket) !!}}
```

Perhaps there is a better solution. !!!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, turn your `$files` array into a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) using `collect($files)` before you pass it to the view (i.e. in your Controller) – this way, Laravel will handle the JSON encoding for you on the fly, so you can just bind it to your component's property in the way you had originally proposed, i.e.

```
<ticket-edit id="edit-ticket" single-ticket="{{ $ticket }}" screenshots="{{ $files }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved! you can use **json_encode** function to convert your array|object to the json string.

```
<ticket-edit id="edit-ticket" 
             :single-ticket="{{ json_encode($ticket) }}" 
             screenshots="{{ json_encode($files) }}">
</ticket-edit>
```