# How to foreach array in laravel + vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I need to foreach array from session. My controller code

```
return [
        'buys' => request()->session()->get('userBuys')
      ];
```

Vue component

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        buys: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
        async getBuys() {
            this.$axios.post('/products/mybuys')
                .then(res => {

                    this.buys = res.data.buys
                    
                    this.$root.hideLoading()
                })
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$root.showLoading()
        this.getBuys()
    }
}
```

So i'm getting array [image: Text]
How i need to foreach this array correctly? I tried a lot of...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass array to Laravel view and use that array as VueJS prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559391/pass-array-to-laravel-view-and-use-that-array-as-vuejs-prop)

Answer (score 0):

You have a json in a array so your

buys = [113, 114,...]

So your loop have only the numbers not the propertys/attributes

Try without brackets:

```
return 'buys' => request()->session()->get('userBuys')
```

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/4gxFqSSbRfmWEqSAXLC1tA.png
and https://image.prntscr.com/image/JQMztieRQuyxxWFUJMYX9w.png
I tried this one

Comment: @AlexeyKotoff so "buys" is empty, please show more code

Comment: buys is not empty https://image.prntscr.com/image/0iAzE7N6Q6SqX6garOtLlw.png

Comment: let me see your whole axios call and where you initialize buys

Comment: check vue component topic

Comment: try to output that in html {{buys}} and show me whats the output

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/N7LdNPkfT96t-wzVxFRwwQ.png

Comment: look at my answer

Comment: i tried, so i'm still getting same
https://image.prntscr.com/image/vw67ABINRWO-KAq_MeqnQw.png
https://image.prntscr.com/image/Dj145PFxRkSiPBYl30mTVw.png